Space Opera Novel search
I remember reading a sci fi series with a female protagonist. I think she had two pet alien "cats". I can't remember too many details - the only scene I can remember fairly clearly, is that she was in a space station public area and an assassin tried to kill her and one of the huge space cats killed the assassin. I think she might have rescued the cats from a smuggler situation. I also think she may have been in charge of the Space Station. Also, just fyi, it's not Honor Harrington.
I think it was at least several books. I'm pretty sure it was a whole series, but I can't remember. Can anyone help?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  How many books were there?  Are you sure it was two cats and not just one?

I can't remember, It's been a while. I think it was at least several books. I think she might have rescued the cats from a smuggler situation. Also, just fyi, it's not Honor Harrington.

It's good you clarified it's not Honor Harrington, else I'm sure at least one answer suggesting it would show up within the hour. :)  Can you give a range of years to "been a while?"  Like, was it before 2010?  After 2015?

I think I've read it in the last 5 years or so, but I'm not sure when it was actually published. I read a lot of space opera/ futuristic stuff and it can be hard to tell. The only scene I can remember fairly clearly, is that she was in a space station public  area and an assassin tried to kill her and one of the huge space cats killed the assassin.

I also think she may have been in charge of the Space Station.

Hi Nicki. I've edited the extra info you've given into your question. Please feel free to undo my changes if you don't like them.

Maybe one of the Telzey Amberdon books? by James H. Schmitz. Her companion "cat"  is the size of a very large tiger or lion. She communicates with them telepathically. They have stealth/chameleon abilities so they can blend in and be unseen even in a room.  (In the first book, she's tells a high planetary official (governor?) the cats are ok if humans hunt them from the ground. But NOT from air cars. (It's Not sporting) and about a dozen(?) cats reveal themselves lounging around in his office to prove their point. But it has been 40+ years since I read the books so don't know if it matches.

There are 2 books in the series, and they are mostly collections of Telzey Amberdon stories published in magazines. There are 2 other books set in the same setting(?) and I cant remember if she was in or mentioned in them.  1: Telzey Amberdon, 2: TNT: Telzey Amberdon & Trigger Argee Together, 3: Trigger and Friends, 4: The Hub: Dangerous Territory.

Those sound interesting but they’re not the books I’m thinking of. I know I’m not giving much detail but it’s all I remember.

@user194956 Hi, if you're "Nicki" who posted the question please merge your accounts so you can regain control of the question and add this as a comment or edit it into the question.

Hmm, Kris Longknife series by Mike Shepherd (or the spin-off Santiago series)?

@NJohnny: If I remember correctly, Telzey's cat companion only figures in the very first short story, which didn't take place on a space station.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen You could be right. As I said its been 40 years since I read them.
